# Helix toolkit WPF CameraController Rotation Mode crash

Tags: c#, wpf, helix

```
control.viewPort.CameraController.CameraRotationMode = CameraRotationMode.Turnball;
```

Throws helpful error

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   your.exe but was not handled in user code"

RotateGesture works, also adding children, but not changes in RotationMode - why?

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You can´t make an instance/object of CameraMode